# Lock screen shown when notification selected

Tags: lock-screens, 4.2-jelly-bean, bugs, nexus-4

I am starting to get some strange behaviour with my Nexus 4 running the latest JB os. I get a notification such as an email or sms, so I unlock the screen before dragging the notification bar down and selecting it. Upon selecting the notification the lock screen pops back up asking me for my pin before sending me to the relevant app.

Any ideas?

Comment: Same thing here. Not sure how the status bar got linked to launch the lock screen.

Comment: I started getting this after I installed and changed some custom lock screens. In particular the neXt launcher and some GO Lock screens. I'm sure it's not issues with those apps but rather some of the settings they changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the problem appears to have been caused by the "manage locking" section of JuiceDefender. Turning that off solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any custom lock screens, un-install them. This will make the annoying behaviour stop. At least it did for me. There was some funky systems settings between the lock screen app and next launcher that you get prompted for. This made the default lock screen come up (not the one I was trying to use).

To recap, this happened with the NeXt launcher (very good, btw), Go Lock Screen and stock android 4.1.1 unrooted on the Samusung Galaxy Note II (Rogers - like AT&T).

Hopefully this helps someone pin down the real reason this happens.